# Warning Code : 1681 UNSIGNED for decimal and floating point data types is deprecated and support for it will be removed in a future release

Tags: mysql

Today I've created a sql backup of a table using SQLyog Community Edition. Then I tried to run the created query against an up to date MySQL 8 managed database on Digital Ocean.

**The query:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE tblUsers (
  id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subscriberId bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  user varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  password varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  created timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  modified timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  status varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  privilege varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  firstName varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastName varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  address1 varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  city varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  state char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  postalCode char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  fax varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  notes varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  payRate varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  pay decimal(8,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**The warning:**

```
Warning Code : 1681
UNSIGNED for decimal and floating point data types is deprecated and support 
for it will be removed in a future release.
```

**The research:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, AUTO_INCREMENT support is deprecated for FLOAT and
> DOUBLE columns; you should expect it to be removed in a future version
> of MySQL. Consider removing the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute from such
> columns, or convert them to an integer type.

**The question:**

I'm not certain how to interpret what I'm reading. Is it really telling me to remove my primary key auto increments? Or is it telling me the `pay` field should no longer be define the way you see above? Or that `AUTO_INCREMENT` cannot exist together with `unsigned`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning is not about your auto-increment column `id`. It's about the decimal column `pay`.

Change this:

```
pay decimal(8,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

To this:

```
pay decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
```

The related excerpt from the manual page you linked to is the following. It tells you what to do if you want to restrict the column to nonnegative values:

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the UNSIGNED attribute is deprecated for columns of type FLOAT, DOUBLE, and DECIMAL (and any synonyms) and you should expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL. Consider using a simple CHECK constraint instead for such columns.

In your case it would look like this:

```
pay decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
CHECK (pay >= 0),
```

Updated example:

- `id` field remains unchanged
- `subscriberId` field loses `UNSIGNED` and gains `CHECK`
- `pay` field loses `UNSIGNED` and gains `CHECK`

```sql
CREATE TABLE tblUsers (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subscriberId` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL CHECK (subscriberId >= 0),
  `user` VARCHAR(16) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `privilege` VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` CHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` CHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `payRate` VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay` DECIMAL(8,2) DEFAULT NULL CHECK (pay >= 0),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=465000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Ahhh. I see. But, what if this field should never contain negative values? Is that no longer explicitly required?

Comment: A `CHECK` constrain. Hmmm.. I'll go research it.

Comment: This might help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: Let me know if there is a comma that needs to separate field name from check.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 will accept an "inline" check constraint for one column as you did in the example, but if you subsequently `SHOW CREATE TABLE` you will see it has changed the constraint to a table constraint. This is handy because it shows the constraint name it has generated. If you want to drop the constraint later, you'll need the constraint name.